# Using data from 1 table to query another table

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have 2 tables. i want to use 'First_Name', and 'Middle_Name' from NAME table to get the 'Description' from DESCRIPTION table. Can i know how to construct this query in both SQL and LINQ expression! thanks alot!

```
CREATE TABLE NAME (
    TICKET_ID int NOT NULL,
    First_Name varchar(255),  
    Middle_Name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (NAME )
);

INSERT INTO @NAME VALUES
(1, 'alex', 'black' ),
(2, 'john', 'hudson'),
(3, 'alice', 'channing')


CREATE TABLE description(
    description_id int NOT NULL,
    First_Name varchar(255),  
    Middle_Name varchar(255),
    Description varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (description_id )
);

INSERT INTO @description
(1, 'alex', 'black' , 'tall'),
(2, 'john', 'hudson', 'strong'),
(3, 'alice', 'channing', 'short')
```

Comment: can u post your expected output..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sql :

`select d.Description from #description d
join #name n on d.First_name=n.first_name  and d.last_name=n.last_name`

Linq :

`from d in description
join n in name on new on new { d.First_name, d.last_name } equals new { n.first_name, n.last_name }
select new { d.Description}`

Comment: for the Linq, is the join n in name on new on new { d.First_name, d.last_name } equals new { n.first_name, n.last_name } correct? im getting a type inference failed in the call to join error

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #NAME (
    TICKET_ID int NOT NULL,
    First_Name varchar(255),  
    Middle_Name varchar(255),

);

INSERT INTO #NAME VALUES
(1, 'alex', 'black' ),
(2, 'john', 'hudson'),
(3, 'alice', 'channing')


CREATE TABLE #description(
    description_id int NOT NULL,
    First_Name varchar(255),  
    Middle_Name varchar(255),
    Description varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (description_id )
);

INSERT INTO #description values
(1, 'alex', 'black' , 'tall'),
(2, 'john', 'hudson', 'strong'),
(3, 'alice', 'channing', 'short')

select Description from #NAME A  join
 #description B on  b.First_Name=a.First_Name  
 and b.Middle_Name=a.Middle_Name
```